# errors during dotfuscator 4.5 task with TFS Build (Team Build with TFS 2008)

Tags: tfsbuild, visual-studio-2008-sp1, dotfuscator

I am invoking dotfuscator task via TFS Build a.k.a Team Build , taken from [**-=Dotfuscator Task with Team Build =-**](http://www.edsquared.com/2007/11/13/Integrating+Dotfuscator+Into+Team+Build+TFS.aspx)and receiving the following error:

```
Build FAILED.


(AfterCompile target) -> 

error MSB4061: The "Dotfuscate" task could not be instantiated from the assembly "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\PreEmptive\Dotfuscator\4.0\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Tasks.dll". 

error MSB4061: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

error MSB4061:    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)

error MSB4061:    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
error MSB4061:    at PreEmptive.Tasks.Dotfuscate.b()
error MSB4061:    at PreEmptive.Tasks.Dotfuscate.a()
error MSB4061:    at PreEmptive.Tasks.Dotfuscate..ctor()
error MSB4060: The "Dotfuscate" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.

    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

THe code relevant to dotfuscator in dotfuscator is as follows:

```
  <!---
  All Dotfuscation Stuff here...
  -->

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConfigPath>$(SolutionRoot)\..\$(BuildDefinitionPath)\BuildType\dotfuscator.xml</ConfigPath>
    <!--<InputPath>$(OutDir)</InputPath>-->
    <InputPath>\\Dev-6\TempBuild\Output\</InputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <InputAssembly Include="$(InputPath)\*.dll;$(InputPath)\*.exe" Exclude="$(InputPath)\*.vshost.exe"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="AfterCompile">

    <!--Perform obfuscation steps after assemblies are compiled.-->

    <Dotfuscate InputAssemblies="@(InputAssembly)" Properties="$(DotfuscatorProperties)" ConfigPath="$(ConfigPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="MappingFile" ItemName="DotfuscatorMappingFile"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="ReportFiles" ItemName="DotfuscatorReportFiles"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="OutputAssemblies" ItemName="DotfuscatedAssemblies"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="SatelliteAssemblies" ItemName="DotfuscatedSatelliteAssemblies"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="DebugSymbols" ItemName="DotfuscatedDebugSymbols"/>
    </Dotfuscate>
  </Target>
  <!-- End of dotfuscation Stuf....-->
```

I am using the following dotfuscator task:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\PreEmptive\Dotfuscator\4.0\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Targets" />
```

The build machine has dotfuscator professional installed. Its fully functional and works fine when used manually.

Kindly help in this problem.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually caused by the build service being run under a different account.  Dotfuscator requires acceptance of the EULA during it's initial execution for each user account it runs under.

You can log into the build server using the account that your build is using, run Dotfuscator and accept the EULA.  Once you have done that future executions under that account will function just fine.

If you are unable to log in to the build server with the build service credentials PreEmptive technical support can provide you with an alternate method to work around this.  You can contact support at support@preemptive.com or file a support ticket directly at http://preemptive.com/support .